# Session destroy in dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, sql

**My problem :** I tried to call session on every dropdown selection.Every thing is fine and working properly but when i come back to this dropdown page, session destroy and show nothing.

**What I want :** I want to maintain session until i don't select next dropdown value.

**My code**

```
<form name="frmdropdown" method="post"  action="index2.php">
        <strong> Select class : </strong> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <select name="empName" id="choice" > 
           <option value=""> Select Class</option> 
        <?php

             $dd_res=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT class from login");
             while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
             { 
                   echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
             }
         ?>
          </select>
 <input type="submit" name="find" value="find"/> 
 <br><br>
 <br><br>
 <?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){


if(isset($_POST['empName']))
      $_SESSION['$cla']=$_POST['empName'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_SESSION['$cla']." where `id` = '1'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     }
       ?>
     </form>
```

Comment: have you tried setting **session_start()** in the being of your php code ?

Comment: Yes,I has included at top.

Comment: I think when we refresh value reflect null at here <option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>